# PHP - str_replace

Tags: php, replace

I'm having some trouble using str_replace, this block below

```xml
|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|
```

when I use this:

```php
str_replace("|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|","a", $registroC100, $replaces);
```

the var `$replaces` increase, but the text keep the same, I'm doing something wrong?

Edit:

this is how is in my code

```php
$registroC100 = str_replace("|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|","a",$registroC100);
```

Comment: Do you use the return value of `str_replace` to update the string?

Comment: I would recommend you review the documentation for [`str_replace()`](https://php.net/str_replace), as the function returns the result of the replacement operation and does not perform it in-place. You'll have to store it in a variable (or pass it to another function, depending on your use case) to use the result later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is simply an incorrect usage of the function and can be easily resolved entirely by reading and understanding the function manual entry as posted in a comment.

Comment: I'm already using the return to update, and tried this same code at 2 site and work.
If I'm using this wrong, can you say where?

Comment: @GuilhermeRodrigues well that is not what your code in the question shows. Please **edit** and show us what you're ***actually doing*** in your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` not changes your variable value unless you do it using the return value of `str_replace` function.

Take a look at the documentation right here https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

```php
<?php
$replaces = 0;
$registroC100 = '|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|';

$registroC100 = str_replace("|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|","a", $registroC100, $replaces);
```

Comment: ...So you read the comments and put them into an answer....

Comment: Feel free to improve the solution bro :)

Comment: first we need to work out what the OP is actually asking....

Answer (score 0):

From your php syntax the str_replace structure and required parameters are okay.

```
str_replace("|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|","a", $replaces);
```

It means search the string stored in variable $registroC100, find the value "|0460|001|CREDITO SIMPLES NACIONAL|", replace it with "a" and count the number of replacement in variable $replace. The problem could be from the value of the string you are searching. What is the value of the variable $registroC100. Show us the variable declaration and initialization.

Comment: _“and count the number of replacement in variable $replace”_ - no, that would be the case if $replace was passed as _fourth_ parameter. In position three, it is the _subject_, the value that you are searching & replacing _in_.